# finding index of all target string in a sequence

Tags: python, list, indexing, substring

Could someone please advise how I can find the index of all target string in a sequence. For example, if I have a string:

```
seq = 'CGCAGCTGCCG'
```

I want to find the index of all 'C' in the sequence. My current code is:

```
for letter in seq:
    if letter == 'C':
        print (seq.find(letter))
```

This however outputs the index of the first 'C' only.

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> seq = 'CGCAGCTGCCG'
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(seq) if x == 'C']
[0, 2, 5, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Is `enumerate` more efficient than doing something like this:
`[i for i in range(len(seq)) if seq[i] == 'C']`

Comment: @ZWiki, According to the `timeit` result, it depends on the size of `seq`: http://pastebin.com/LeFCVT46

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to get the `ind /index` of each `C` in the string

```
indexes = [ind for ind,ele in enumerate(seq) if ele == "C"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the regex function `re.finditer`:

```
impor re
seq = 'CGCAGCTGCCG'
index = [m.start(0) for m in re.finditer('C', seq)]
```

However, it seems to be slower for this particular sequence:

```
>>> %timeit [m.start(0) for m in re.finditer('C', seq)]
2.74 µs ± 719 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(seq) if x == 'C']
1.57 µs ± 433 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```